# How do I install the new beta driver for Nvidia?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, beta

How do I install the new beta driver for Nvidia?

With Ubuntu before 12.04 I could do this:

1) Downloaded it from the site [www.nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com/)

2) Logout,

3) Move to tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>),

4) Stop lightdm or gdm (`sudo service lightdm stop`)

5) Remove any nvidia driver (`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current nvidia-settings`)

6) Cd into downloaded folder (`cd ~/Downloads/`)

7) Run the installer (`sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-***.run`)

But this doesn't work anymore, i.e., after reboot I am presented with a very low graphic resolution (something about 320 x 400).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could install the new Nvidia beta 302 by adding the xorg-edgers ppa:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

Then update the system (the driver will be pushed automatically):

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

To revert (downgrade) use ppa-purge:

`sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not fix the bug [#752445](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/752445)

Answer (score 0):

Why no just open the ADDITIONAL DRIVERS in the PREFERENCES panel and select the POST_RELEASE version of the driver?

Comment: Thank you for posting. This doesn't solve because then I stick with the 290.40 driver which has a few issues that seems to be solved with 302. Also I don't want to downgrade to 290.33 because of the vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this also. Check out the "dmesg" output. My installation was complaining about a Nvidia version mismatch between the kernel module and the driver. I think reinstalling the kernel fixed it, but I did a ton of stuff.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will try that and let you know the results.

Comment: Do you mean `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-\`uname -r\`` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Fixed above.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not worked. Have to re-install nvidia drivers with `jockey`.