# How to run a .run file as root?

Tags: drivers, command-line, root

I downloaded a .run file for a Nvidia driver, but when I run it in the terminal it tells me it must be run as root.

I'm a complete noob and I barely even know what root is. I think it's somewhere around the equivalent of admin in windows.
[image: driver run as root]

Well, I got the file to run but it turns out that the driver will not recognize my card.
I've heard about other problems with Nvidia cards not working right with 64 bit versions of 12.04.

Comment: If you are, as you say, a complete noob, perhaps there is a better and easier way to do what you're doing.  Are you simply trying to install the Nvidia driver?  There is a point and click interface for that - look for "Additional drivers" under your system settings.  If you have already tried that, could you let us know, and what went wrong?

Comment: In case your are not so experienced with Ubuntu I would go a step further and like to discourage you from installing graphic drivers other than through the methods mentioned above.

Comment: Also if you want to test a beta driver, look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/131150/nvidia-beta-driver-in-ubuntu-12-04/142848

Comment: There are no drivers under the "additional drivers" setting.

I don't need to be discouraged, how else will I learn but through trial and error?

Beta driver? I will look into that. I have plenty of time to re-install ubuntu thousands of times.

Comment: @neon_overload, I know this is an old thread, but I would just like to point out that I had to install "Additional drivers" from the Ubuntu Software Center, as it didn't show up by default

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to do two things; both from a Terminal prompt:

1. Change to the directory where you have the `.run` file stored.
2. Type: `chmod 755 filename.run`
3. Type: `sudo ./filename.run`

The above commands will make the file executable and will launch the executable with root-level permissions.

Comment: But the file ran OK, obviously, so why confuse him with unnecessary steps?  Also, you should specify that "filename" is not to be typed literally, but substitutes for the name of the .run file.

Comment: It's alright, I understood it.
I had to google some things but in the end it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add the command "sudo" before the command. For example: sudo blah.sh

After you enter your password the command will run as root. Be careful to verify the trustworthiness of a package or command before running it with sudo.

Comment: PS you really should read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: Of course, if the command is `./blah.sh` then to run it as root you would do `sudo ./blah.sh`, rather than `sudo blah.sh` (which would only run `blah.sh` if it's in the `$PATH`).

Comment: Attention, must possibly use gksudo for graphicals...

Answer (score 1):

`root` is the master account in Ubuntu; every account has limited privileges but the `root` account has no limitations. The reason for hiding `root` is that in most cases you don't need root access. The analog in Windows would be having to authenticate when you want to install a driver; in Ubuntu you have to be root or have root privileges.

There are two ways for you to get access as root. You can type:

`sudo <whatever-command>` and Ubuntu will ask you for your password and then execute that command as root.

OR

`sudo su`, where you'll input your own password and then you will become root (i.e. you will be logged in as root).

I prefer the latter because it gives me more control; sometimes running a command just as root isn't enough, but doing it this way can be more dangerous (i.e. you could accidentally cause more damage).

I recommend trying the first way. And then trying the second way if  that doesn't work. Just make sure you get out of root after you're done (i.e. type `exit` after you're finished doing what you need to do as root).

Comment: `sudo -s` is widely considered preferable to `sudo su` (though this may have more to do with elegance than anything else). To get a `root` shell that behaves like an actual `root` login, use `sudo -i` instead. (This is similar to `sudo su -`.) Also, `logout` will not work to get out of a `sudo su` shell, because such a shell is not a login shell. You need to use `exit` instead.

Comment: @EliahKagan Cool! I didn't know about `sudo -i`/`-s`. Good point on `exit`, I mistyped that. I'll edit the entry above. Can you explain why `sudo -s` is more "elegant"?

Comment: Sure, but first some background so that the explanation can be beneficial to others. `su` and `sudo` are two separate mechanisms for running a command as a some user, who may be different from the user invoking them. (If not otherwise specified, `su` and `sudo` will run--or attempt to run--the command as `root`.) Since `su` authenticates with the *target* user's password, and password authentication for `root` is turned off by default (and not recommended or officially supported) in Ubuntu, you cannot use `su` to become `root`, but `root` can certainly use `su` to become some other user.

Comment: `sudo` and `su` are both capable of running a single command. `sudo` does this by default and `su` does this when given the `-c` flag. They are also both capable of starting a shell. `sudo` does this when given the `-s` flag (or `-i` to simulate an initial login shell), and `su` does this by default (or when given the `-` flag, to simulate such a login shell). When you run `sudo su`, you are becoming `root` with `sudo`, and then *becoming root again as root* (i.e., `root` `su`-ing to itself), to start a shell. It's more elegant to just "change" identity once and start the login shell...

Comment: **...which is what `sudo -s` (or `sudo -i`) accomplishes.** `su -c 'sudo ...'` (with `...` replaced by a command) would be similarly inelegant. Commands like `sudo bash` are considered a bit inelegant for a different, related reason--`sudo` has the `-s` and `-i` flags to start a shell however you like, so one may as well use them. While these ways are *inelegant* (and subtly different in their effects from the suggested `sudo -s` and `sudo -i`), they are not actually *bad* and they *work fine*, so it's OK to go on using them if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

If you have enabled the root account you can use

```
su
```

Enter the password for root, `cd` to your application folder, then run

```
./package.run
```

Comment: In Ubuntu root isn't setup for login / su with password as default, so the above wont work out of the box.