# What to do after Installing 12.04 LTS via WUBI?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wubi, codecs

I just installed Ubuntu via WUBI and I have a few questions:

1. How would I know if my video card's driver is installed and if not, how do I install it?
   I have NVIDIA GT220 1GB. I don't see proprietary drivers in the system settings.
2. How do I install all codecs in Ubuntu? Something like K-lite codec pack or CCCP for Matroska?
3. How do I make Ubuntu look like Windows? I don't like the launcher on the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as knowing if your video card's driver is installed, you can look under System Settings --> Details.  Also you can click on Additional Drivers, to see if any drivers needed.

[image]

For installing Codecs, you need to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras.  You can do that from the Ubuntu Software Center, or by clicking below

[image]

As far as making Ubuntu look like window, Why?:) You can do that  by installing themes.  You just have to look for one that you like, and install it.  Also you may want to take a look at [LXDE](http://lxde.org/).  I have tried installing the Windows 7 theme, but with no luck.

Comment: I went to details and it shows me that the driver in "NONE" and experience is "STANDARD" does that mean that my video card is not compatible?

Comment: That means that you need a driver for your VGA card.

Comment: I found the driver for NVIDIA GeForce GT220 in the website but it is downloaded as a .run file. How do I install it?

Comment: Take a look at [Install .run Files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144422/how-to-run-a-run-file-as-root)

Answer (score 1):

1) open `jockey-gtk`

2) go to `software-center` and install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

3) just [use this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/55985/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7/) and find others on Google about how to make Ubuntu look like Windows 7