# How to install .run file in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install NVIDIA.run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run)

hello everyone  I am new in ubuntu and i really like it's too comfortable for any H/W but i have problem in it i want to install graphic driver of nvidia geforce 610m series.
I already use these command

1. `cd 'path of my removable drive'`
2. `chmod -x nvidia.run`
3. `sudo ./nvidia.run`

after run these command my terminal show

> sudo:./nvidia.run : command not found

please help me

Comment: Also check this question: [how to run a .run file as root?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144422/how-to-run-a-run-file-as-root)